# .net6 does not have quick fix running on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c#, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, .net-6.0

Already installed c# extensions.

Tried quick fix with dotnet core 3.1 and net 5 (both are working for quick fix)
Except net 6 (asp.net webapi) having this issue. (console application works fine)

How may I fix this? Appreciate any helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out the problem was the dotnet 6.0.200. Reverting it back to dotnet 6.0.102 resolves the issue.